# SQL Server error with insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table `AuditTrail`.

When I run this query:

```
INSERT INTO AuditTrail
                     ( EntityName, Date, [User], Action, OldValue
                      , NewValue, ModuleName, EntityRef, EntityAttribute
                      , EntityAltRef) 
VALUES (aaa, '2012-02-07 00:00:00.000', sa, DELETE, '11', aaa, aaa, sa, aaa, aaa)
```

I get an error

```
Incorrect Syntax Near Keyword 'DELETE'
```

What am  I doing wrong here?

Here is the table structure

```
ID                numeric(18, 0)  Unchecked
EntityName        nvarchar(60)    Unchecked
Date              datetime        Unchecked
[User]            sysname         Unchecked
Action            varchar(30)     Unchecked
OldValue          varchar(1024)   Checked
NewValue          varchar(1024)   Checked
ModuleName        varchar(6)      Checked
EntityRef         varchar(30)     Checked
EntityAttribute   varchar(60)     Checked
EntityAltRef      varchar(64)     Checked
```

Comment: You're not quoting a lot of things that look like they ought to be strings.

Answer (score 2):

Add `'` between sa and delete.

```
INSERT INTO AuditTrail ( EntityName, Date, [User], Action, OldValue, NewValue, ModuleName, EntityRef, EntityAttribute, EntityAltRef) 
VALUES ('aaa','2012-02-07 00:00:00.000','sa','DELETE','11','aaa','aaa','sa','aaa','aaa')
```

sa is default admin user and delete is a keyword in SQL, you must insert them as literals that is why you have to encapsulate them by `'`, I assume that `aaa` is a string value as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `DELETE` is a reserved keyword so you should escape with quotes, to let database undestand it is a a field and not a command. You are also using

```
INSERT INTO AuditTrail ( EntityName, Date, [User], Action, OldValue, NewValue, ModuleName, EntityRef, EntityAttribute, EntityAltRef) VALUES (aaa,'2012-02-07 00:00:00.000',sa,'DELETE','11',aaa,aaa,sa,aaa,aaa)
```

Check your other fields and remember that not integers column's values need to be surrounded with quotes `'`

Answer (score 1):

DELETE is command and you can't use it directly.Put single quote around it , so databae will understand that it is string and not command.

```
INSERT INTO AuditTrail
                     ( EntityName, Date, [User], Action, OldValue
                      , NewValue, ModuleName, EntityRef, EntityAttribute
                      , EntityAltRef) 
              VALUES (aaa,'2012-02-07 00:00:00.000'
                     ,sa,'DELETE','11',aaa,aaa,sa,aaa,aaa);
```